# How to I open a word document stored in a database using .Net

Tags: .net, database, word-automation

I have several MS Word documents stored as BLOBs in a SQL Server database.

I need to be able to:

1. Open the document
2. Set a few DOCVARIABLEs
3. Print the document

I am very familiar with Word automation but I don't know how to open a document from the database. I am also open to solutions other than automation if they will accomplish the result.

I would very much like to avoid using a temporary file.

History:

I am rebuilding a legacy system written within Access 2003. The legacy system uses a control called UnboundObjectFrame to which the value is assigned. The frame then exposes appropriate automation objects. I can't find any equivalent control in .Net.

Jacob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only option is to create a temporary file. Office does not support opening documents from any sort of memory stream or byte array. If you don't know how to programmatically query a database column and create a temporary file, please post a new question.

Comment: If "Office does not support opening documents from any sort of memory stream or byte array" then the legacy system wouldn't be able to do it either. Clearly office is capable of opening a file from memory or it wouln't be able to now.

Also Outlook permits all kinds of documents to be opened from memory. Even an email is really a Word document opened from memory.

Comment: The legacy system doesn't do this. Office does not support this. Peruse the API and you will find nothing that supports loading from memory. In every case -- e.g., opening a document from the web, or from Outlook -- the document is saved to a temporary file first.

Comment: You can, however, use the Open XML SDK to create/modify documents in memory, but you don't have access to any of the automation features. You won't be able to print. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx

Comment: When I assign data to the UnboudObjectFrame I immediately get access to a property containing a Word.Document object. If a temporary file is being created then Office is doing it completely behind the scenes.

Also, I can create a document (or email) using automation, manipulate it in memory, and print it. This all works seamlessly without needing to save to a file.